# empty localStorage before headers are set

Tags: php, javascript, database, html, local-storage

is there any way to empty localStorage (defined in html5) through php?

I need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.localStorage.clear();
</script>

<?php header('Location: '.$adress); ?>
```

But unfortunately its not possible to call javascript before headers :(

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: just use javascript to redirect

Comment: Always remember (in this scenario): JavaScript is client side, PHP is server side. (And thus, the server first does everything server side, and afterwards, when it is sent to the user, the JavaScript will be executed by the user/client and NOT by the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: you will need to do the redirection in Javascript as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.location = "<?= $adress ?>";
</script>
```

You can only manipulate `localstorage` with Javascript, and if you send the `Location` header with PHP the Javascript will not be executed.

Comment: It is slow solution, but looks like the only one :( Thank you.